# Comparing a list within a Dictionary to another Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find a way to list information about a user and display facts about a city they are interested in. If a city listed is within the dictionary of cities I want to display facts about that city. I'm very new to Python and I'm kind of stuck on this problem.

```
favorite_places = {
    "zac": ["tokyo", "denver", "rotterdam"],
}

cities = {
    "tokyo": {"population": 13000000, "fact": "Tokyo is Japan's largest city.",},
    "montgomery": {
        "population": 50000,
        "fact": "Montgomery is home to multiple military installations.",
    },
    "rotterdam": {
        "population": 620000,
        "fact": "Rotterdam has the largest sea port in Europe.",
    },
}

for name, place in favorite_places.items():

    print("\n {}'s favorite places are:").format(name.title())

    print("{}").format(place)

    for city, fact in cities.items():

        if place == city:

            print("\n Here are so facts about {}:").format(city.title())

            print(fact)
```

Comment: Hi Zak, welcome to the Python family!  Could you maybe post a mockup of the output?  Also, your code looks pretty cool, in what way does it fall short?  (ie: doesn't run, or doesn't produce any output, etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
for place in favorite_places['zac']:
  if place in cities:
    print(cities[place])
```

This should work. All you want to do is loop over the `favorite_places` list however that list is located within a dictionary so to access it you would want to index the dictionary `favorite_places` at `zac` since that is the name of the key which corresponds to the value of the list. So you would want to loop over `favorite_places['zac']` instead.

Within the first for loop , the variable `place` will now be assigned to each place in `favorite_places['zac']`. Then, You want to check if the current `place` is in the cities dictionary. You can do that by writing `if place in cities`. If they are, then print the info, otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few pointers that will help you:

- `.format` is a string method so you need to call format on a string,
  not on a `print`.
- you don't need to iterate over `cities` dictionary you can directly
  do a lookup if the city exists like this `cities.get(place)`.

```
for name, places in favorite_places.items():
    print("\n {}'s favorite places are:".format(name.title()))
    print("{}".format(places))

    for place in places:
        if cities.get(place):
            print("\n Here are so facts about {}:".format(place.title()))
            print(cities[place])
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I went with

for user in favorite_places:
      print(user)
      for place in favorite_places[user]:
        if place in cities:
          print(cities[place])

worked out just fine and cleared some things up.